# Error occurred while executing doInBackround method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtimeexception

I am sending details to be stored in a database using a web service using KSOAP.There is nothing wrong with the web service it works fine. This code worked when i didn't user AsyncTask class. I am new to android and this is the first time i tried using the AsyncTask class and it does not work. I have attached the log cat errors, something is wrong with the doinbackround method. What am I doing wrong? Please help

```
public class Registration extends Activity{
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/register";
private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "register";
private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:54714/WebSite1/Service.asmx";
Button sqlRegister, sqlView;

EditText  sqlFirstName,sqlLastName,sqlEmail,sqlMobileNumber,sqlCurrentLocation,sqlUsername,sqlPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.registration);
sqlFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFname);
sqlLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLname);
sqlEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
sqlMobileNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
sqlCurrentLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCurrentLoc);

sqlUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
sqlPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPwd);

sqlRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
sqlRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bRegister:
        new LongOperation().execute("");
        break;
      }
     }
    });
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         String firstname = sqlFirstName.getText().toString();
         String lastname = sqlLastName.getText().toString();
         String emailadd = sqlEmail.getText().toString();
         String number = sqlMobileNumber.getText().toString();
         String loc = sqlCurrentLocation.getText().toString();
         String uname = sqlUsername.getText().toString();
         String pwd = sqlPassword.getText().toString();

         SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
         Request.addProperty("fname", String.valueOf(firstname));
         Request.addProperty("lname", String.valueOf(lastname));
         Request.addProperty("email", String.valueOf(emailadd));
         Request.addProperty("num", String.valueOf(number));
         Request.addProperty("loc", String.valueOf(loc));
         Request.addProperty("username", String.valueOf(uname));
         Request.addProperty("password", String.valueOf(pwd));
         Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "You have been registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.dotNet = true;
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
         HttpTransportSE httpTransport  = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
         try
         {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
             int result =  Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
             if(result == '1')
             {
                 return "Registered";
             }
             else
             {
                 return "Not Registered";
             }
         }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return null;

    }      

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result=="Registered")
        {
        Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "You have been registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(result =="Not Registered")
        {
        Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Somethings wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
    }   
 }
```

[image]

////Edited

```
public class Registration extends Activity{
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/register";
private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "register";
private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:54714/WebSite1/Service.asmx";
Button sqlRegister, sqlView;

EditText  sqlFirstName,sqlLastName,sqlEmail,sqlMobileNumber,sqlCurrentLocation,sqlUsername,sqlPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.registration);
sqlFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFname);
sqlLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLname);
sqlEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
sqlMobileNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
sqlCurrentLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCurrentLoc);

sqlUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
sqlPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPwd);

sqlRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
sqlRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bRegister:
        new LongOperation().execute("");
        break;
      }
     }
    });
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         String firstname = sqlFirstName.getText().toString();
         String lastname = sqlLastName.getText().toString();
         String emailadd = sqlEmail.getText().toString();
         String number = sqlMobileNumber.getText().toString();
         String loc = sqlCurrentLocation.getText().toString();
         String uname = sqlUsername.getText().toString();
         String pwd = sqlPassword.getText().toString();

         SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
         Request.addProperty("fname", String.valueOf(firstname));
         Request.addProperty("lname", String.valueOf(lastname));
         Request.addProperty("email", String.valueOf(emailadd));
         Request.addProperty("num", String.valueOf(number));
         Request.addProperty("loc", String.valueOf(loc));
         Request.addProperty("username", String.valueOf(uname));
         Request.addProperty("password", String.valueOf(pwd));

         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.dotNet = true;
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
         HttpTransportSE httpTransport  = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
         Log.d("work","work");
         try
         {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
             int result =  Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
             if(result == 1)
             {
                 Log.d("reg","reg");
                 return "Registered";
             }
             else
             {
                 Log.d("no","no");
                 return "Not Registered";
             }
         }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return null;

    }      

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("tag","onpost");
        if(result!=null)
        {

            if(result.equals("Registered"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "You have been registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else if(result.equals("Not Registered"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Somethings wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }

    }
```

}

Comment: and its still not working, right?

Comment: ya not working :( Only the log message work is being displayed in log cat

Comment: try logging what string is returned, and tell us

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

1. Always keep the UI work in UI thread, and Non-UI work in Non-UI thread.
2. doInBackground is a Non-UI thread, so you can NOT post anything on the UI thread
      from this.
3. The Toast statement is the problem in doInBackgroud, move it to postExecute, which is
      working on UI thread.

   ```
   Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "You have been registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   ```

Comment: Thanks i removed the toast from the doinbackround() now i dont get any error but the problem is nothing happens. None of the toasts are displayed

Comment: Are the toast that you have declared in doPost displaying ??

Comment: wait for the task in doInBackground to finish, to see the toast. keep Log statements to know whats happening

Comment: please don't use bold text in 90% of the answer. Just highlight a few words, not complete sentences.

Comment: Thanks..i will try to get hold of my obsession for bold letters.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling

`Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "You have been registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

inside doInBackground(), which not running in UI thread. That causing the problem.

Try this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "You have been registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
}
```

or move the `Toast.makeText` to onPostExecute() method, which running in UI thread

Comment: I removed the Toast from the doInBackground(). I don't get any errors but nothing happens when i click on the Register button. None of the toasts are displayed :(

Comment: How can the Toast displayed if you removed it? And you don't have to remove it. Try the code I post above. Run the `Toast.makeText` inside runOnUiThread. It should works.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling Toast in the doInBackground(). Whatever UI in doInBackground will make the looper() exception. so try to make the UI in the PostExecute() in AsynTask
as

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

 Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "You have been registered Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
 }
```

It may helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

you should not compare strings using `==`.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result=="Registered")
```

That could be the reason behind the unexpected behavior. Try using something like

```
result.equals("registered")
```

read [this](http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/)

Comment: Changed both still not working :/ None of the toast are displayed.Check my edit

Comment: use logs, or console output to check whether your `onPostExecute()` is being called.

Comment: onPost is not being called.I used logs.Only the "work" log is displayed in the log cat